# How to get list of devices with yellow exclamation mark in Device Manager Windows - c++

Tags: c++, windows, wmi

i am using msdn WMI sample code to get the list of devices that show up in the device manager with yellow exclamation mark but its only returning a list of all properly 
installed devices on the machine. Could anyone here help me reslove this problem only using c++.
Thanks

```
    void GetUnKnownDeviceList()
{
    HRESULT hres;
    hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,
                                 RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL); 

    IWbemLocator *pLoc = 0;
    hres = CoCreateInstance( CLSID_WbemLocator, 0, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, (LPVOID *) &pLoc);
    IWbemServices *pSvc = 0;                  

    hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),NULL,NULL,0,NULL,0,0,&pSvc);

    hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE,  NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL,
                             RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE);       

    IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = NULL;    
    hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
            bstr_t("WQL"), 
            // bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity"), DOES NOT LIST DEVICES SHOWING WITH YELLOW EXCLAMATION MARK
            bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode = 0"), // LIST ONLY PROPERLY INSTALLED DEVICES
            WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY, 
            NULL,
            &pEnumerator);

    IWbemClassObject *pclsObj;
    ULONG uReturn = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
        VARIANT vtProp;
        hr = pclsObj->Get(L"Name", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
        TRACE("Device Name : %s\r\n\", vtProp.bstrVal);
        VariantClear(&vtProp);
        pclsObj->Release();
   }    

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To list he devices that aren’t working yoou need query for all devices with a ConfigManagerErrrorCode other than 0,  you must modify your WQL sentence to.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_PnPEntity WHERE ConfigManagerErrorCode <> 0
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, after modifying WQL sentence to what you suggested i am getting ERROR hr=1,pclsobj=NULL and uReturn=0 in the below function                                                                        HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);

Comment: instead of `while(1)` use `while(pEnumerator)`

Comment: still the same, i have put a break point in the loop and the function  pEnumerator->Next(..)inside the loop is returning error. pEnumerator is valid pointer though, i checked.

Comment: No i am getting the same error from that code too  hr=1,pclsobj=NULL and uReturn=0   <pre><code> HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn); The only difference between the code sample u mentioned is this function hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"\\\\.\\root\\CIMV2"),...) and one i am using is pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"),...); Ahhh so fustrating...

Comment: i have a work around. Once i get the list of devices that are working through my code above. I do another search with the below function and then compare both lists and devices that dont match are the ones that show up as yellow exclamation mark in the device manager. Thanks RRUZ for the help though. While(!SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,SPDRP_DEVICEDESC,
  &DataT,(PBYTE)buffer,buffersize,&buffersize))
{
 CString csThisDevice = CString(buffer);
 TRACE ("Devices Found: %s\n", csThisDevice);
}

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using setupapi for this? I think you should be able to enumerate the device node list of known and unknown devices with it.

Comment: The setupapi function gives error=13, i.e."The data is invalid" for unknown devices when the below function is called using SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE option which is not correct and does not match to the error codes mentioned in the msdn documentation. However the function do return correct value for KNOWN devices. SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty(hDevInfo,&DeviceInfoData,SPDRP_INSTALL_STATE,...)

Answer (score 0):

it's possible to use wmi with this example in c#:

```
/ Query the device list trough the WMI. If you want to get
// all the properties listen in the MSDN article mentioned
// below, use "select * from Win32_PnPEntity" instead!
ManagementObjectSearcher deviceList =
new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select Name, Status from Win32_PnPEntity");

// Any results? There should be!
if ( deviceList != null )
// Enumerate the devices
foreach ( ManagementObject device in deviceList.Get() )
{
    // To make the example more simple,
    string name = device.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
    string status = device.GetPropertyValue("Status").ToString();

    // Uncomment these lines and use the "select * query" if you 
    // want a VERY verbose list
    // foreach (PropertyData prop in device.Properties)
    //    Console.WriteLine( "\t" + prop.Name + ": " + prop.Value);

    // More details on the valid properties:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(VS.85).aspx
    Console.WriteLine( "Device name: {0}", name );  
    Console.WriteLine( "\tStatus: {0}", status );

    // Part II, Evaluate the device status.
    bool working = (( status == "OK" ) || ( status == "Degraded" )
        || ( status == "Pred Fail" ));

    Console.WriteLine( "\tWorking?: {0}", working );
}
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30031/Query-hardware-device-status-in-C

just change the status or ConfigManagerErrorCode to get the kind of error tou look for.